# add specific string at the beginning and at the end of line 1

Tags: text-processing

The input file looks like this

```
H1 O1 C1 H2 H3 C2 H4 H5 O2 C3 H6 H7 C4 H8 H9 O3 C5 H10 H11 C6 H12 ......
```

I would like to have the following output file

```
z(A) H1 O1 C1 H2 H3 C2 H4 H5 O2 C3 H6 H7 C4 H8 H9 O3 C5 H10 H11 C6 H12 ...... OW HW1 HW2
```

so as to include at beginning of line the "z(A)" and at the end "OW HW1 HW2"

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e '1s/^/z(A) /' -e '1s/$/ OW HW1 HW2/' < input > output
```

`1` is for the first line, `s` is for substitute, `^` is beginning-of-line, `$` is end-of-line.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==1{print "z(A) " $0 " OW HW1 HW2"; next}1'
```

or

```
awk 'NR==1{printf "z(A) %s OW HW1 HW2\n", $0; next}1'
```

or

```
awk 'NR==1{$0="z(A) " $0 " OW HW1 HW2"}1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same file, you can try :

```
printf '%s' 'Z(A) ' "$(<infile)" 'OW HW1 HW2' >infile
```

Comment: Though that adds the prefix and suffix to the start and end of the _file_, not the start and end of the first _line_.

Comment: @ilkkachu you are right, don't seen the line 1 in the tittle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ sed '1{s/^.*$/Z(A) & OW HW1 HW2/}' input > output
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the scriptable editor `ed`!

```
printf '%s\n' '1s/^/z(A) /' '1s/$/ OW HW1 HW2/' 'wq' | ed -s filename
```

This prints the following three newline-separated commands to `ed`, who we ask to silently edit the given `filename`:

- `1s/^/z(A) /` -- as in the `sed` answers, on line 1, replace the beginning of the line with the text `z(A)`.
- `1s/$/ OW HW1 HW2/` -- as in the `sed` answers, on line 1, replace the end of the line with the text `OW HW1 HW2`.
- `wq` -- write the changed file back to disk and quit